# How to separate json files by a value in a file using python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to separate a set of json files based on the value in the file and write to separate folders using python.
I'm stuck at how to add a filter.
sample json -

tried this -

```
testdir = /tmp
var = "hailey"
for infiles in glob.glob(os.path.join(testdir, '*.json')):
    with open(infiles, 'r') as outfile:
        finalfile = json.load(outfile)
        if 'value:'+var in [finalfile['value']]:
            ....
```

```
{
  "n1": {
    "type": "F1",
    "type2": "F2"
  },
  "value": "hailey",
  "circles": {
    "type": "P1"
  },
  "notes": "good feeback",
  "types": [
    {
      "n1": "key",
      "c1": "comments",
      "t1": "type"
    }]
}
```

Comment: The sample you provided is not legal JSON. Additionally, provide an example of what you tried, and show how it fails.

Comment: rather, illegal json >>

Comment: updated, tried only to read files iteratively.

Comment: There is value to showing what you've done even if it's trivial. It is not easy to understand from your question what is it that you want to do. Do you want to separate the file into several JSON files? What do you mean by "based on the value in the file"?  What do you mean by "add a filter"?

Comment: the values for the key "value" there could be 2 different values as "hailey" and "none". There are 10 json files in a direcotry, want to separate files with values as "hailey" and write to different directory. so can use only those files. [OR] if I know how to parse data while checking for filter condition on the file would be nice.

Comment: Specifically, what value do you want to use, and how do you want to group on that value?

Comment: added more details,not successful in adding filter for separation of files.